# After fat is burned from one part of the body, is fat moved around the body?

Tags: physiology, fat-metabolism

If you go running, for example, and burn fat from your legs, does your body send fat from other parts of the body to that area? If so, why would it do this?

Answer (score 2):

Fat burning is a generalized procedure so there is no such a thing that some part of body loses fat and other part gains it.

`Targeted Fat Loss` still is a [myth](http://www.yalescientific.org/2011/04/targeted-fat-loss-myth-or-reality/).